# ROS Environment variables not set after new Humble install on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, environment-variables

I carefully followed the install instructions for installing ROS2 Humble binary.

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

The install had no errors. And I did the talker-listener test to make sure.

But none of the ROS environment variables are set.

When I type `printenv` I don't see `ROS_VERSION=2`,`ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3` or `ROS_DISTRO=humble`.

The tutorials page just says to go back to the installation page or get help from the community. So here I am :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have those environment variables exported in every command line automatically, the easiest thing to do is to add `export VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE` for each one at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file.

After saving, you need to open a new terminal window or call `source ~/.bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

**Edit:**

You shouldn't have to export those variables by yourself as those are taken care of by the `setup.bash` script inside your ros humble instalation.

Please make sure you have your ros installation sourced in `~/.bashrc` via `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash`

[Docs here](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten the step of sourcing the setup.bash script.